# Web browser control default IE version

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

I have an Embedded browser in my WPF application. I have used Windows Forms Web browser control by using Windows forms host. I know that Web browser control is a wrapper around Internet Explorer Active x. Which version of IE does Web browser control takes by default. I read some where as it takes IE 6.0 and in some sites as IE 7 compatibility mode. I would also require to upgrade the version of IE in registry. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have much choice, it's whatever Internet Explorer version is installed.

In IE 8+, by default the content of a WebBrowser control is in IE7 Standards Mode, see the following IEBlog posts:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/24/ie9-s-document-modes-and-javascript.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/06/17/compatibility-view-and-smart-defaults.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx

There's probably something normative in MSDN library.

Answer (score 0):

basically is IE7. may use below javacript to check IE version

```
alert('IE '+document.documentMode+'\n\n'+navigator.userAgent)"
```

you may set the browser emulation version by registry of FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"myprogram.exe"=dword:00002af8

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"myprogram.exe"=dword:00002af8
```

for details, may refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

or "A Brief Guide to FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" at https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2016/01/a-brief-guide-to-feature_browser_emulation/